# multiple image upload using foreach loop and inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multifile-uploader

I am having trouble getting the image files I wanted them to insert in my database I want the
picture like the one I uploaded like this:

```
insert into('pic1.jpg');

insert into('pic2.jpg');

insert into('pic3.jpg');
```

not like this:

```
insert into(Array[0] => pic1.jpg, Array[1] => pic2.jpg, Array[2] => pic3.jpg);
```

so i can get their name only and insert in in  my database
im required to use  **foreach loop**

```
  if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
      $upload[] = ($_FILES['images']['name']);
      print_r($upload);
   }


<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
        <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple">
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ...

```
   foreach ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $val ) {

        $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
        $filesize = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
        $filetempname = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

        $fileext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $fileext = strtolower($fileext);

        // here your insert query
    }
```

Comment: so you mean for inserting 10 image, he have to make **10** query to database ??

Comment: @@Alireza Fallah... that is his requirement

Comment: is it possible to upload images using multiple browse buttons?

Answer (score 3):

This is also one method:

```
foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $f => $name) {
 $filename = $_FILES['images']['name'];
 $mysql_query1 = mysql_query("insert into table values('".$filename."')");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$images = $_FILES['images']['name'];
$sql = "insert into table (image_name) VALUES  ('".  implode("') ('", $a)."')";
```

Result is like :

```
insert into table (image_name) VALUES ('1.jpg') ('2.jpg') ('3.jpg') ('4.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

user foreach.

example code :

```
foreach ($image as $image_path)
{
    mysql_query("insert into `table` (column) values ('".$image_path."')");
}
```

Comment: you mean for 10 image, he must make 10 queries instead of one??

Comment: so u want to 10 images each in one row !! so there will be 10 queries for sure

Comment: insert into('pic1.jpg');

                insert into('pic2.jpg');

                insert into('pic3.jpg');

he want like this i guess

Comment: i wanted to loop until all the images are in my database so that will require a long code.
so i ask how to use the foreach loop with array instead of for loop its much neater.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
 $total = count($_FILES['images']['name']);
 for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){

  $tmpFilePath=$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];
  if($tmpFilePath != ""){


    $img_name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];

    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) value ('".$img_name."')");
    }    
  }  
}
```